# How to read JSON using Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json

To read JSON using as3, are there any built in methods?
It would be better if we get some code samples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the JSON classes in the as3corelib library
http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

```
basic use:
var obj:Object = JSON.decode(jsonString);
var str:String = JSON.encode(myObject );
```